# The opposite act of blowing your nose

Tags: word-request, translation

You know when you get *runny, bunged up, or stuffy* nose, you tend to blow it but sometimes it can be so frequent that you're not up to it anymore and simply try to *breathe it in*. Or another example is when a co-worker standing next to you who has a cold, too, looking at the blueprint with you and continuiusly is making this wierd sucking slurpy noise with his nose which is really disgusting, too (at least to me, no offence). Technically it's blowing your nose just the other way around.

1. What do you call it in English? And if there are some informal words to describe it, please bring them up, too.

> > (In my native language we say *"pull up the nose"*)

2. What do you call a person who's always like this, I mean, a person who has stuffy nose almost always and doesn't like to blow his nose and instead just breathe it in.

> > (In my native language we call the person informally *"snotty"*, although in English they use *snotty* to describe a thing dirty with mucus)

Thanks

Comment: I'd call that 'sniffing' (Br Eng)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[snuffle](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/snuffle) - to ​breathe in ​quickly and ​repeatedly through the ​nose, usually because you are ​crying or because you have a ​cold

> I can't stand your **snuffling** any longer.

[snotty](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/snotty) has more than one meaning- one of which is 'covered in snot'. It doesn't really describe the breathing in.

**snuffler** is not in the dictionary, but everybody would know what you mean if you said it about somebody that does it all the time.

> He's a snuffler.

Comment: This is a minor nitpick, but I would say "Sniffle" instead. "Snuffle" sounds a little weird to me.

Comment: **Sniffle** and **snuffle** are variants. Maybe sniffling is a little gentler than snuffling.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem, it's a word that you learned from your mother. Like mother's apple pie, once you have decided one of these words is best, you will stick with it. For BrE, snuffle is, and always has been, ahead (but not by much). For AmE, snuffle is pretty stable but sniffle goes up and down with fashion: at the moment, sniffle is ahead.

Comment: Is it then OK e.g to say to your friend with whom you're comfortable and he has a stuffy nose, "snuffle it completely, or go blow you nose. You're making me sick"?

Comment: It's probably a different usage of _sniffle_ that I'm trying to use but I'm asking this to see what you can say in this situation too since we use the same word in this context that I just put up too i.e. to empty the contents of your nose by sniffling it. Can I say, "snuffle it completely"?!

Comment: @Yuri: It's OK to talk to somebody about snuffling, but I can't imagine anybody saying "snuffle it completely", because what they have to do next is swallow it, which is (for me at least) gross. Just "Blow your nose, you're making me sick".

Comment: I see, thanks JavaLatte and all. BTW how about _snort it down_ if I say this in this specific context, can a native speaker make sense of it or still I sound wierd and gross too? :)

Comment: Snorting certainly has the connotation of breathing rapidly through the nose, but with the exception of recreational drugs, it doesn't have the 'moving solids' connotation. It does have other meanings too: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/snort

Comment: @JavaLatte You think it's "gross", and yet you do it all the time; mucus produced in your lungs is pushed up by the cilia up into the throat, then swallowed. That's why you swallow so much. It's a perfectly natural thing to do. ;-)